# Как сравнить два объекта одного класса? C++

Tags: c++

Проблема заключается в следующем,я не знаю как взять результат из объекта 1 и объекта 2 и сравнить их.
Вот мой код.
Мне нужно взять и сравнить вычисленные значения для двух объектов класса, в моем случае это результаты вычислений площади и периметра квадрата с разными значениями переменной на входе.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// начало объявления класса
class Square // имя класса
{
public: // спецификатор доступа
    int S, P; // объявление переменных для расчёта площади и периметра
    
    int calc_s(int a) 
    {
        S = a * a;
        return S;
    }
    
    int calc_p(int a) 
    {
        P = 4 * a;
        return P;
    }

    void enter_S(int b)
    {
        cout << "Площадь квадрата: " << S << endl;
    }

    void enter_P(int b)
    {
        cout << "Периметр квадрата: " << P << endl;
    }

    

}; // конец объявления класса Class

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    
    int a = 2;
    int b = 4;

    Square objclass; // объявление объекта
    objclass.calc_s(a); // вызов функции класса calc_s (тут у нас считается площадь)
    objclass.calc_p(a); // вызов функции класса calc_p (тут у нас считается периметр)
    objclass.enter_S(objclass.calc_s(a));
    objclass.enter_P(objclass.calc_s(a));

    Square objclass2; // объявление 2-го объекта
    objclass2.calc_s(b); // вызов функции класса calc_s (тут у нас считается площадь)
    objclass2.calc_p(b); // вызов функции класса calc_p (тут у нас считается периметр)
    objclass2.enter_S(objclass.calc_s(b));
    objclass2.enter_P(objclass.calc_s(b));
    
    
    if (tie(a) == tie(a))
    {
        cout << "Площадь квадрата объекта A > объекта B " << endl;
    }
    else if (objclass.calc_s(a) == objclass2.calc_s(a))
    {
        cout << "Площадь квадрата объекта B = объекта A " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Площадь квадрата объекта B < объекта A" << endl;
    }
    
    if (objclass.calc_p(b) > objclass2.calc_p(b))
    {
        cout << "Периметр квадрата объекта A > объекта B" << endl;
    }
    else if ((objclass.calc_p(b) == objclass2.calc_p(b)))
    {
        cout << "Периметр квадрата объекта B = объекта A" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Периметр квадрата объекта B < объекта A" << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если будут вопросы спрашивай. А вот рабочий код

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    
    int a = 4;
    int b = 2;

    Square objclass; // объявление объекта
    objclass.calc_s(a); // вызов функции класса calc_s (тут у нас считается площадь)
    objclass.calc_p(a); // вызов функции класса calc_p (тут у нас считается периметр)
    cout<<"Объект А с стороной: "<< a<<endl;
    objclass.enter_S(objclass.calc_s(a));
    objclass.enter_P(objclass.calc_s(a));
    
    Square objclass2; // объявление 2-го объекта
    objclass2.calc_s(b); // вызов функции класса calc_s (тут у нас считается площадь)
    objclass2.calc_p(b); // вызов функции класса calc_p (тут у нас считается периметр)
    cout<<"Объект Bс стороной: "<< b<<endl;
    objclass2.enter_S(objclass.calc_s(b));
    objclass2.enter_P(objclass.calc_s(b));
    cout<<"*********"<<endl;
    if( objclass.calc_s(a)==objclass2.calc_s(b)) cout<<"площади объектов равны"<<endl;
    else if( objclass.calc_s(a)>objclass2.calc_s(b)) cout<<"площадь объекта A > площади объектa B "<<endl;
    else cout<<"площадь объекта  A < площади объектa B "<<endl;
    
    
    if( objclass.calc_p(a)==objclass2.calc_p(b)) cout<<"периметры объектов равны равны"<<endl;
    else if( objclass.calc_p(a)>objclass2.calc_p(b)) cout<<"периметр объекта A > периметра объектa B "<<endl;
    else cout<<"периметр объектв A < периметра объектa B "<<endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "int a =4 ;" 
Стоило бы воспользоваться этим, прежде чем выкладывать код
https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=EtGLX7TlAamJrwSnhJnQCA&q=cpp+formating+online&oq=cpp+formating+online&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCAAQzQI6BAgAEEc6BAgAEA06CAgAEBYQChAeOgYIABAWEB5Qmx9YijpghjtoAHABeACAAZABiAG-BZIBAzUuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi0tqX3sr3sAhWpxIsKHSdCBooQ4dUDCA0&uact=5

Comment: "Рабочий" значит его можно скопировать и запустить и он будет работать? Если да, то это не так https://godbolt.org/z/j1z9aG. Лучше добавить всё необходимое